# function to join Char array incl additional sign in between

Tags: c++, arrays, arduino

I've tried to solve it for half a day... without success...

I have an Struct:

```
typedef struct s_iomodus {
const char* SENSOR; 
const char* POSITION_1;
const char* SHOW_MI;
const char* POSITION_2;
const char* TYPE_1;
const char* TYPE_2;
const char* DESCRIPTION;  // LOC Description of the
const int NRVALUES;
} iomodus_t;

iomodus_t iomodus[] = {
{ "Relay","WW_Tank","WW_Pumpe_An_Aus","NO_P2","NO_T1","NO_T2" ,"MAGNETIC", 1}, //D25 :
{ "Relay","Puffer_Tank","NO_SHOW","NO_P2","NO_T1","NO_T2" ,"SSR", 1}, //D26 :
{ "Relay","WW_Tank","Valve","Auslauf_unten","Zu","Auf" ,"MAGNETIC", 2}, //D27 :
```

where i store all STATUS QUO setup of all PINS and the Position, which i send as a topic to MQTT server..

now i have to build from this array a string to send it in VOID SETUP as a

```
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);

  MQTTclient.setServer(server, 1883);
  MQTTclient.setCallback(callback);
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  // Allow the hardware to sort itself out
  delay(1500);

 const char *c_topic = concat_strings(iomodus[i].POSITION_1,iomodus[i].SENSOR, iomodus[i].POSITION_2);

      Serial.println(c_topic);
      MQTTclient.publish(c_topic, iomodus[i].VERSION);

    }
```

my problem is... that the function does not make the right string
**It does not add "/" in between !**
It should be the String like this:
"MQTTTOPIC_PREFIX/TEXT_str1/TEXT_str2/TEXT_str3"
or
"MQTTTOPIC_PREFIX/TEXT_str1/TEXT_str2/TEXT_str3/TEXT_str4" **if str4 is there/not empty**

```
const char *concat_strings(const char *str1, const char *str2, const char *str3,const char *str4)
{
  // define a buffer
  static char result[MAX_CONCAT_LEN] = {0};

  // counter part
  int i = 0;
  const char *slash = {"/"};
  const char *PREF= {MQTTTOPIC_PREFIX};
  size_t len = strlen(PREF)+strlen(str1)+strlen(str2)+strlen(str3);

  // loop until end of ID has reached or destination buffer is full
  while(*PREF && i < MAX_CONCAT_LEN)
    {result[i++] = *PREF++;}
  // loop until end of string 1 has reached or destination buffer is full
  while(*str1 && i < MAX_CONCAT_LEN)
    {result[i++] = *str1++;}
  // loop until end of string 2 has reached or destination buffer is full
  while(*str2 && i < MAX_CONCAT_LEN)
    {result[i++] = *str2++;}

if (str3==TRUE){
// loop until end of SLASH has reached or destination buffer is full
  while(*slash && i < MAX_CONCAT_LEN)
    {result[i++] = *slash++;} 
  while(*str3 && i < MAX_CONCAT_LEN)
   { result[i++] = *str3++;}
   }    

 if (str4==TRUE){
// loop until end of SLASH has reached or destination buffer is full
  while(*slash && i < MAX_CONCAT_LEN)
    {result[i++] = *slash++;} 
  while(*str4 && i < MAX_CONCAT_LEN)
   { result[i++] = *str4++;}
   }      

  result[len+1] = 0;

  return result;
}
```

so even though I do it this way... it does not add "/" and does not want to recognize, if str3 or str4 is FALSE...

Please, what is the easiest way to join the array and add "/" if str3 or str4 is available (str1 and str2 is always there)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This would be a lot easier if you could use `std::string`s.  Can you use them?

Comment: @NathanOliver I was tempted to advise the same first. I think it's different on [tag:arduino], it's not really standard c++ they use.

Comment: _@Max_ Why not simply use [`strcat()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat)?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: i tried it, but it didn't work ...that is the last version i used to do it nearly manualy ;-) How could it look like after you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems in the code:

- First, it would be better to declare `result` outside the function:

  ```
  static char result[MAX_CONCAT_LEN] = {0};
  ```
- Declare the function with a default value for `str4`:

  ```
  const char *concat_strings(const char *str1, const char *str2, const char *str3,const char *str4 = NULL);
  ```
- Don't compare `char*` with `TRUE`, use `NULL` instead:

  ```
  if (str4 != NULL){
  ```
- Between `PREF`, `str1` and `str2`, there is no code to add the seperator:

  ```
  while(*PREF && i < MAX_CONCAT_LEN)
    {result[i++] = *PREF++;}
  // loop until end of string 1 has reached or destination buffer is full
  while(*str1 && i < MAX_CONCAT_LEN)
    {result[i++] = *str1++;}
  // loop until end of string 2 has reached or destination buffer is full
  while(*str2 && i < MAX_CONCAT_LEN)
    {result[i++] = *str2++;}
  ```
- In `str4`, `slash` is pointing to the end of the string due to:

  ```
    while(*slash && i < MAX_CONCAT_LEN)
      {result[i++] = *slash++;}
  ```

  in the previous loop. (you normally don't need a loop here, unless the seperator could be more than one character in the future)
- `len` isn't adjusted when `str4` is present:

  ```
  size_t len = strlen(PREF)+strlen(str1)+strlen(str2)+strlen(str3);

  result[len+1] = 0;
  ```

  which cuts off `str4` anyway.

When possible, it would be better to use the [`String` class](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringObject), or [`strcat()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/).

For some examples of string concatenation with the Arduino `String` class, see [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StringAdditionOperator), [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StringAppendOperator) and [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StringConstructors).

```
 // adding a constant integer to a string:
  stringThree = stringOne + 123;

  // adding a constant long interger to a string:
  stringThree = stringOne + 123456789;

  // adding a constant character to a string:
  stringThree = stringOne + 'A';

  // adding a constant string to a string:
  stringThree = stringOne +  "abc";

  // adding two Strings together:
  stringThree = stringOne + stringTwo;
```

Comment: I knew that arduino has some propriatetary implementation of strings. Good point.

Comment: @Danny_ds: sorry...didn't work with string library yet...how would it look like with you suggestion?? Thank you in Advance!

Comment: @Max - Something like: `String stringOne =  String(stringTwo + " with more"); // concatenating two strings` - see [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringConstructor) for some examples, or [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StringConstructors) for a tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are hell-bent on sticking with C functionality and `const char*` strings. There are a couple more useful C string functions like `strlen` and `strcopy`. As you will notice from the C API, when dealing with raw `char*` strings, it is standard practice to issue a buffer into which the function should write its results, so it is clear whose responsibility it is to clean the string up (in that case: the caller's!). Therefore, you can do the following (tested [here](http://cpp.sh/8d3s)):

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

bool strconcat(char* result, unsigned int bufsize, const char* s1, const char* s2, const char* s3, const char* s4) {
    const char* strings[4] = {s1, s2, s3, s4};
    for(unsigned char i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        const char* s = strings[i];
        if(!s)
            return true;
        unsigned int len = strlen(s);
        if(len > bufsize)
            return false;
        strcpy(result, s);
        bufsize -= len * sizeof(char);
        result += len * sizeof(char);
        if(i < 3 && strings[i+1]) {
            if(bufsize > 0) {
                result[0] = '/';
                --bufsize;
                ++result;
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int main()
{
  char result[80] = {0};
  const char* a = "ab";
  const char* b = "xyziuehfih";
  const char* c = "ihihfeih";
  strconcat(result, 80, a, a, b, 0);
  std::cout << result << "\n";
}
```

Comment: thanks working like charm... heve to rewritze my code...i will give feedback later, when it working withhte whole code... THANK YOU!